# set_memory_* functions in Linux Kernel >=2.6.25

Tags: kernel, rootkit

I'm doing research about rootkits and I have received a lot of warnings like`

```
"BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at [addr]"
```

when I tried to attach my own function to `sys_call_table[__NR_read]`, for example.

In kernels <=2.6.25, function `change_page_attr()` helped with changing page attributes of a certain address. However, in new kernels >=2.6.28, this function is deprecated and is replaced with `set_memory_*` functions, related to PAT.

The Linux kernel documentation is not clear about PAT functions usage; I have used `set_memory_wc()` & `set_memory_uc()` to change the `sys_call_table` permissions but I continue receiving the same BUG. That functions I guess are replacing the old `change_page_attr()`.

I saw one example in i915 module, and I have used functions in same way, but the BUG continues.

Any help about it? Am I handling in wrong way kernel addresses?

Answer (score 2):

I've tested with 2.6.26 and 2.6.30 debian kernel specific.

for 2.6.26 `set_memory_wc` and restoring with `set_memory_wb` works.

2.6.30 doesn't work if there's `CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA` in Kernel Hacking ( I think ). Haven't had the time to actually recompile, but I've tested with a custom kernel which doesn't have that.

in 2.6.30 `set_memory_rw` and `set_memory_ro` are exported as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why must one _restore_ after setting to a mode other than writeback? I've also read in the Linux docs that `set_memory_[uc|wc|wt] ` and `set_memory_wb` should be used in pairs to return the mode to writeback after use, but no explanation regarding the motivation is included.